# how to create a jar including specific packages?

Tags: java, maven, jar

Lets say I have following package structure and I'd like to create a jar which only contains everything under `**/var/`* and its dependencies. (excluding `**/foo/*`, `**/something/*` and  `**/dummy/*`).

```
`src/main/java/my/package/foo/`
`src/main/java/my/package/var/`
`src/main/java/my/package/dummy/`
`src/main/java/my/package/something/`
```

Once I have the jar, how do I install the jar into local m2 repo?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is tagged with Maven... are you using Maven to build your project?

Comment: Yes. I need to configure pom file to do this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [maven-jar-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html) to accomplish this.

Ex:

```
<plugin>   <!-- jar plugin -->
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
         <execution>
              <id>jar-with-var</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                   <goal>jar</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                     <archive>
                        <index>true</index>
                        <manifest>
                               <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <classifier>jar-with-var</classifier>
                    <includes>
                       <include>path/to/your/files/*</include>
                    </includes>
               </configuration>
          </execution>
    <executions>
</plugin>
```

The above will create a jar with the classifier `-jar-with-var.jar` appended to the end of it, named for your artifact id, containing all files in the includes block.
Likewise, you can also create a jar file that excludes files explicitly as well. The reference linked should show you how to do that.

> Once I have the jar, how do I install the jar into local m2 repo?

Use the maven-install-plugin to set up an additional install goal

```
<plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.5.2</version>
     <executions>
          <execution>
               <id>jar-with-var</id>
               <phase>install</phase>
               <goals>
                    <goal>install-file</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <groupId>your group id</groupId>
                    <artifactId>the desired artifact id</artifactId>
                    <version>your version</version>
                    <file>your created jar file</file>
                </configuration>
          </execution>
     </executions>
</plugin
```

When you run `mvn install` with this POM, it will package up your jar, create your artifacts, and install them to your local .m2 repo